# Is there a way to match the exact record in a multiple-Condition elasticsearch BoolQuery?

Tags: elasticsearch, query-builder

I have an application in which I use elasticsearch as my search engine and I have a problem that I need help with.

In my search query, I want to get a document that contains a ***reference type*** with the value "**NVE**" and a ***reference value*** with the value "**8005267293**"

Below is a snippet of the document I want to get looks like this

```
.......
  "addresses": [],
  "references": [
                    {
                        "type": "FBA",
                        "value": "0000765855"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "GEN",
                        "value": "0082467914"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "GEN",
                        "value": "0000765855"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "GEN",
                        "value": "0006418559"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "NVE",
                        "value": "8005267293"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "NVE",
                        "value": "000000008005267291"
                    }
                ],
........
```

My issue is my query actually returns the document as expected but if I change the value of **references.type** to "**GEN**" or "**FBA**", it still returns the document but I want it only to return the document if the ***references.type*** is "**NVE**" and the ***references.value*** is "**8005267293"**

For my search query, this is what I used

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "references.type": "NVE"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "wildcard": {
                            "references.value": "*8005267293*"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using the default mapping or defined `references` field as an object data type which looses the relationship between the properties as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects).

You need to use the [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested) for your `references` field and use [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-fields-array-objects) for getting expected results.

Comment: Thanks Ammit, changing the mapping to nested made it work!